# Browser titles are being passed instead of the custom titles in Google Ananlytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics, google-analytics-4

I have noticed with user_engagement and session_start events in GA4, the browser titles are being passed instead of the custom page_title that we are passing.

Here is the code to pass the custom page_title:

```
`/**
* Generate the custom dimention title based on the input URL
* @param {string} url 
* @return {string}
*/
const generateCustomDimensionTitle = (url: string): string => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
    const type = urlParams.get(LOCATION_TYPE);
    const tab = urlParams.get(LOCATION_TAB);
    const section = urlParams.get(LOCATION_SECTION );
    const sectionItem = urlParams.get(LOCATION_SECTION_ITEM );
    const tabTitleStr = tab ? ` > ${tab}` : "";
    const title = section ? `${type} > ${section} > ${sectionItem}${tabTitleStr}` : `${type}${tabTitleStr}`;
 
return title;
};
 
/**
* Push URL data to google tag manager
*/
export function pushUrlDataToGtm(): void {
    if (window.dataLayer) {
        // google tag manager is loaded 
        const pageUrl = window.location.href;
        const pageTitle = generateCustomDimensionTitle(pageUrl);
 
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: "virtualPageview",
            pageUrl,
            pageTitle,
        });
    }
}`
```

Below is the variable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVgVH.png)

Below is the Google Tag that is sending page_title with the trigger
Trigger:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zksuc.png)

Google Tag:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64P7M.png)

I also have a GA4 event that fires a page_view that passes the page_title & url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wwet.png)

**Can you tell me what to do from Google sending window page_title instead send this custom page_title**